# Calculate pps for DDoS evaluation

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service

I am working on a task where I have to evaluate how much throughput one can generate in packets per second. I know I can send them as fast as possible with `hping3 [...] --flood`, but is there a way to calculate their number reliably for a single host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the attack you want to generate(Attack type), the capacity of your single host (CPU, Memory), and on the network capacity (Bandwidth), and also on the application that is receiving the requests in the case is a L7 attack, and probably more variables to take into consideration.

Comment: I already have the network capacity, how do I get the host's capacity? An example would be using hping3 for a TCP-SYN attack.